# How do i change mouse cursor in Amchart

Tags: amcharts

I have an bar column amchart and have click event on each column. But how can i change the mouse cursor to other icon (like hand) to make user know that the column 's clickable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [showHandOnHover](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showHandOnHover) if you want mouse pointer to change to hand when hovering the graph

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the [rollOverGraphItem](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#rollOverGraphItem) and [rollOutGraphItem](http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#rollOutGraphItem) event to toggle a class to your chart container and set the cursor with css :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with CSS use the class `amcharts-graph-column`, whilst setting `addClassNames` to true on your [AMChart config](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart). (Version 3)

This allows for a column to have a cursor, without the whole chart looking clickable, and doesn't need to register any extra event handlers.